# Сподвигло или подвигло?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

В разговорной речи порой использовал слово "сподвигло", но стал писать комментарий в Интернете, и оказалось, что данное слово выделяется как ошибка.

Я собирался его использовать в данном предложении: *"Должно быть, это сподвигло бы меня туда ходить".*

**Мой вопрос:** Хочется услышать комментарии по этому поводу и узнать, возможно ли его использовать или нет.

**P. S.** "Сподвигло" для меня означает "побудило", "склонило".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Глаголы "подвигнуть и сподвигнуть" отличаются по стилю:** подвигнуть ― **высокий и нейтральный** стиль, иногда со значением иронии (в Нацкорпусе 130 примеров), сподвигнуть ― **сниженный стиль, обычно со значением иронии** (в Нацкорпусе 10 примеров).

Примеры: Стремление к идеалу способно **подвигнуть** людей на любые жертвы. [М. М. Гурвич. Модные и новомодные диеты // «Наука и жизнь», 2007] Эти новые обстоятельства должны были, видимо, оживить нас и **подвигнуть** на покупку. [Андрей Колесников. Исповедь участника лотереи  1997.09.02]

Необычность ситуации вполне могла **сподвигнуть** грузчиков на кражу. [Екатерина Романова, Николай Романов. Дамы-козыри (2002)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Викисловарь**: ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/подвигнуть, **в нем указана форма "сподвигнуть" как устаревшая с тем же значением.**

Выделяются **две группы устаревших слов**:1) **историзмы** – слова, называющие устаревшие вещи и явления, и 2) **архаизмы**– устаревшие слова, которые называют предметы и явления, существующие и сейчас, но имеющие иные обозначения. Историзмы не имеют синонимов в современном русском языке. Архаизмы, напротив, имеют в современном языке синонимы, с помощью которых толковые словари разъясняют их значение, сопровождая их пометой устар.: благость – 'книжн., устар. Доброта, милосердие.

**Особенно интересна судьба архаизмов, к которым можно отнести глагол "сподвигнуть" .** Такие слова употребляются носителями языка, но воспринимаются ими как устаревшие. Нередко слова, будучи устаревшими в прямом значении, продолжают жить в языке на правах общеязыковых метафор.Также устаревшие слова могут обретать "вторую жизнь", возвращаясь вновь в активное словоупотребление. http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/41.htm

Язык –  это динамическая система, в нем постоянно происходят различные изменения, в то время как словари фиксируют значения слов в период своего издания, а издаются они не так часто.

Возможно, что устаревший **глагол "сподвигнуть" в настоящий момент приобрел ярко выраженное ироническое значение и уже не является синонимом глагола "подвигнуть",** но это еще не отражено в словарях.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ! Посмотрите пожалуйста, мой комментарий к первому(на данный момент) сообщению здесь. При написании слова `сподвигнуть` в интернете, его подчеркивает красным цветом, как ошибку, т.е. это может означать, что нет такого слова в русском языке. В интернете(используя поисковик), как раз возникает  проблема  в том, что где-то отвечают, что нет такого слова и следовательно его использовать не нужно, а где-то(как у вас) что вроде, использовать можно и далее "правила" где и как лучше его использовать.

Comment: Программы, подчёркивающие красным, пишутся простыми смертными на основе имеющихся у них списков слов - не стоит воспринимать такие пометки как приговор. Ирония, придаваемая этим словом, в некоторой степени вызывается ассоциацией его с выражением "сдвинуть с места" - единожды "подвигнуть" на не свойственный кому-то поступок.

Comment: Я поставил плюсы данным ответам, но я не могу их принять, т.к. ответ должен содержать главное(один из двух вариантов): 1). Слово `сподвигло`есть в русском языке и его можно использовать в устной/письменной речи. Здесь дополнительно можно привести примеры его использования.  2). Такого слова нет в русском языке, и его лучше не использовать. Напишите тогда вы  @Alex_ander такой ответ. Первый ответ(на данный момент) намекает на то, что слова такого нет, но это так явно не указывается, а довольно пространно. Второй ответ намекает, что слово можно использовать.

Comment: Викисловарь: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/подвигнуть, в нем указана форма сподвигнуть как устаревшая с тем же значением. Такие слова  употребляются носителями языка, но воспринимаются ими как устаревшие. Нередко слова, будучи устаревшими в прямом значении, продолжают жить в языке на правах общеязыковых метафор.Также устаревшие слова могут обретать "вторую жизнь", возвращаясь вновь в активное словоупотребление. Возможно, глагол "сподвигнуть" приобрел ярко выраженное ироническое значение  и уже не является синонимом глагола "подвигнуть", но это еще не отражено в словарях.

Comment: @Sibylla Мне понравилось ваше объяснение, пожалуйста, дополните свой ответ им(отредактируйте свой ответ) и я его приму. Видимо простого и понятного ответа на мои вопросы(см. комментарий выше) мне не получить, но если вы пожелаете, можете еще дополнить свой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Орфографический [словарь, что на Грамоте.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C), единственный после Даля фиксирует глагол "сподвигнуть" с пометой *сниженное* по отношению к "подвигнуть".

У Даля же:

> **СПОДВИЗАТИ**, сподвигнуть кого на что, побуждать, поощрять, одушевлять, ободрять, направить на какую либо деятельность. -ся,
>   соподвизаться, соратовать, соусердствовать, соревновать кому; |
>   подвизаться на каком-либо поприще. Сподвижник, -ница, со участник в
>   каком-либо общем подвиге. Сподвижники 1812-го года.

Но Даль нам в правописании не указ...

Справка Грамоты.ру долго отвечала вопрошающим, что нет такого слова - *сподвигнуть*, от него в нормативной речи сохранился лишь [сподвижник](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), а [потом сдалась](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зато на глагол "подвигнуть" с истовым рвением отзываются все словари:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрите [страничку 675 Розенталевых "Трудностей"](http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/trudnostej/slovar-trudnostej_0675.htm) - не фиксируется глагол "сподвигнуть".

[Словарь трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке:](http://diffc_ru.academic.ru/5736)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Цитата:

"В языке обычно выделяют четыре основных уровня: фонетический, морфологический, лексический, синтаксический. Языковые единицы каждого из этих уровней могут быть ***либо стилистически нейтральными, либо стилистически окрашенными.***"

**[источник](http://lit.lib.ru/m/martinowich_g_a/03stlokrlex.shtml)**

"Сподвигнуть" не является стилистически нейтральным словом, а имеет стилистическую окраску.

> Стилистически сниженная лексика — это лексика, отличающаяся от
>   литературного языка или языкового стандарта. Языковой стандарт же —
>   это образцовый, нормализованный язык, нормы которого воспринимаются
>   как «правильные» и общеобязательные.

**[источник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/599591/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)**

Comment: Avanesova Благодарю за ваш ответ! Хочется уточнить, вопрос был именно о "существовании" слова `сподвигнуть` как такового, т.к. если в литературном русском языке нет этого слова, для меня очевидно, что его лучше не использовать. Так как, в дальнейшем на данную тему возможно будут ссылаться поисковики, хорошо бы, чтобы вы написали(возможно вверху вашего сообщения, жирным шрифтом) 1). Есть такое слово или нет 2). Стоит его использовать или нет. Для ищущих ответ в интернете, возможно это упростит задачу в будущем.

Comment: Орфографический словарь обязан фиксировать слова, функционирующие в языке, для избежания именно орфографических ошибок. Но пометы - *обл., сниж., ирон.* и т. д. - выделяют их из нормативного (литературного) языка.